Ubuntu 24.04 Dead plus Key
I am new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu on my PC.
Everything seems to work fine, and I think in the beginning ply plus key worked, but since yesterday my plus key does not work anymore. I used some tools (showkey and xev) but I did not get any signals from the Key. On my Windows Machine, the key still works, so the problem seems to come from Linux. I also tried all Keyboard Layouts, but it did not help.
Keyboard Layout: German
Keyboard: Razer Huntsman Mini
